# What is meaning of assume char set is ASCII?

Tags: data-structures

I was solving below problem while reading its solution in first line I read this
can anyone help me in explaining assume char set is ASCII **I Don't want any other solution for this problem I just want to understand the statement **

Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters.  What if you can not use additional data structures

> Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 1):

There is no text but encoded text.

Text is a sequence of "characters", members of a character set. A character set is a one-to-one mapping between a notional character and a non-negative integer, called a codepoint.

An encoding is a mapping between a codepoint and a sequence of bytes.

Examples:

- ASCII, 128 codepoints, one encoding
- OEM437, 256 codepoints, one encoding
- Windows-1252, 251 codepoints, one encoding
- ISO-8859-1, 256 codepoints, one encoding
- Unicode, 1,114,112 codepoints, many encodings: UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32,…

When you receive a byte stream or read a file that represents text, you have to **know the character set and encoding.** Conversely, when you send a byte stream or write a file that represents text, you have let the receiver know the character set and encoding. Otherwise, you have a *failed communication.*

Note: Program source code is almost always text files. So, this communication requirement also applies between you, your editor/IDE and your compiler.

Note: Program console input and output are text streams. So, this communication requirement also applies between the program, its libraries and your console (shell). Go `locale` or `chcp` to find out what the encoding is.

Many character sets are a superset of ASCII and some encodings map the same characters with the same byte sequences. This causes a lot of confusion, limits learning, promotes usage of poor terminology and the partial interoperablity leads to buggy code. A deliberate approach to specifications and coding eliminates that.

Examples:

- Some people say "ASCII" when they mean the common subset of characters between ASCII and the character set they are actually using. In Unicode and elsewhere this is called [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/).
- Some people say "ASCII Code" when they just mean codepoint or the codepoint's encoded bytes (or code units).

---

The context of your question is unclear but the statement is trying to say that the distinct characters in your data are in the ASCII character set and therefore their number is less than or equal to 128. Due to the similarity between character sets, you can assume that the codepoint range you need to be concerned about is 0 to 127. (Put comments, asserts or exceptions as applicable in your code to make that clear to readers and provide some runtime checking.)

What this means in your programming language depends on the programming language and its libraries. Many modern programming languages use UTF-16 to represent strings and UTF-8 for streams and files. Programs are often built with standard libraries that account for the console's encoding (actual or assumed) when reading or writing from the console.

So, if your data comes from a file, you must read it using the correct encoding. If your data comes from a console, your program's standard libraries will possibly change encodings from the console's encoding to the encoding of the language's or standard library's native character and string datatypes. If your data comes from a source code file, you have to save it in one specific encoding and tell the compiler what that is. (Usually, you would use the default source code encoding assumed by the compiler because that generally doesn't change from system to system or person to person.)

The "additional" data structures bit probably refers to what a language's standard libraries provide, such as list, map or dictionary. Use what you've been taught so far, like maybe just an array. Of course, you can just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, assume that character codes will be within the range 0-127. You won't need to deal with crazy accented characters.

More than likely though, they won't use many, if any codes below 32; since those are mostly non-printables.

Answer (score 0):

Characters such as 'a' 'b' '1' or '#' are encoded into a binary number when stored and used by a computer.

e.g. 
'a' = 1100001
'b' = 1100010

There are a number of different standards that you could use for this encoding. ASCII is one of those standards. The other most common standard is called UTF-8.

Not all characters can be encoded by all standards. ASCII has a much more limited set of characters than UTF-8. As such an encoding also defines the set of characters "char set" that are supported by that encoding.

ASCII encodes each character into a single byte. It supports the letters A-Z, and lowercase a-z, the digits 0-9, a small number of familiar symbols, and a number of control characters that were used in early communication protocols.

The full set of characters supported by ASCII can be seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII